# How can I get average from a polymorphic relation in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

So I have a feedback model as a many to many polymorphic relation, for now I can say:

```
$user->feedbacks
```

and it will retrieve the relation accordingly, now I want to do something like:

```
$user->feedbacks->getAverage()
```

to simply spit the average feedback rating (which are numbers from 1 to 5)

I added the following function to my Feedback.php model file:

```
public function getAverage(){

    $described = $this->avg('described');
    $recommend = $this->avg('recommend');
    $communication = $this->avg('communication');

    $average = ($described + $recommend + $communication) / 3;

    return $average;
}
```

But Laravel will not recognize this method.

Please help.

Comment: I found a workaround for this in my User model instead I placed this function:

    public function getAverageFeedback(){

        $feedbacks = $this->morphToMany(Feedback::class, 'feedbackable');

        $described = $feedbacks->avg('described');
        $recommend = $feedbacks->avg('recommend');
        $communication = $feedbacks->avg('communication');

        $average = ($described + $recommend + $communication) / 3;

        return $average;
    }
But I still don't know if it is the best approach for this

Answer (score 1):

The method should be on the User model. If you look at the chain of objects, you are trying to call the getAverage method on a Collection class instance (that's what querying a Model for related Models will return for you). A collection doesn't have a method named getAverage().

To solve your problem, create the getAverage() method on the User model and inside of it, fetch the related Feedback model collection and compute the average based on the retrieved Models.